# MVC app works fine in chrome, Firefox but not in IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I have a small MVC app, all this app must do is to take search string parameter via text-box and search the database return the data based on the parameter entered. This app works fine in the two of the browser that I have on my machine, it works in chrome and firefox but goes to complete freeze on IE11, it freezes so much so that it cannot even open developer tools nor respond to any click on the landing page.

I am not even too sure what code should I post because I doubt it has something to do with it and if does go down to code I am not sure which part because like I said it works perfect in chrome and firefox

I tried adding the line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` on the layout page but that made no difference whatsoever

Comment: did you solve the problem

Comment: Nope, still battling, you know I thought perhaps it just my IE, I have then deployed to QA and send the URL to my colleague but still same issue, IE is freezing but other browsers work like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Typically inability to open dev tools in a browser indicates that something intensive is running in a background. Try to open dev tools prior to entering URL of your application. Sometimes you can find some request looping forever, or wrong javascript.